# How to find non-existing terms based on the list?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, drush

I've few thousands terms in my vocabulary. I'd like to find out which one still are missing (without adding them) based on the list of term names.

I believe this can be achieved by some [anti-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join) sql query, but any solution would be fine.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7. If you get an empty array you know the term doesn't exist yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is in text file (`list.txt`), this can be achieved by `grep` comparision.

First, extract the list of terms from the database by drush:

```
$ drush sqlq "SELECT name FROM taxonomy_term_data -- WHERE vid = 1" > my_list.txt
```

Then compare the two lists:

```
$ grep -Fxv -f my_list.txt list.txt
```

This will print all the term names which doesn't exist in `my_list.txt` file.

This solution is based on: [Is there a tool to get the lines in one file that are not in another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another).